# How to assert array json in groovy

Tags: arrays, json, groovy, jsonslurper

My JSON response looks like below

```
{
    "pCategories": [
        "pogc1",
        "pogc16",
        "pogc2",
        "testc1122",
        "testcat10012018",
        "testcat10012019",
        "testcat100120191",
        "testcat11012018",
        "testcat12012018",
        "testcat120120181",
        "testcat20112017",
        "testcat20112018"
    ]
}
```

I have used the below code to assert.

```
def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response.asString())
assert slurped.pCategories.contains("$category")
```

But getting an error.

How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because "$category" is not a String. It is an instance of GStringImpl.

```
def category = 'pogc16'
assert 'pogc16'.equals("$category") // false
```

To fix your code you can convert "$category" to String:

```
assert slurped.pCategories.contains("$category".toString())
```

Comment: Still i am getting below error
    assert slurped.pCategories.contains("$category".toString())
           |       |                 |          |         |
           |       |                 false      |         testcat21Feb20181144
           |       |                            testcat21Feb20181144
           |       [pogc1, pogc16, pogc2, testc1122, testcat10012018, testcat10012019, testcat100120191, testcat11012018, testcat12012018, testcat120120181, testcat20112017, testcat20112018, testcat21feb20181142, testcat21feb20181144]

Comment: at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.assertFailed(InvokerHelper.java:399)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.assertFailed(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:648)
        at a_orepim_getproduct_categories.getlistofcategories(a_orepim_getproduct_categories.groovy:129)

Comment: Oh.. take a look at your values. 'testcat21Feb20181144' != 'testcat21feb20181144'  'F' letter

Comment: Yes i tried with converting the category into .toLowerCase(),then it's working.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Need a little help over here. It's still unclear what you're actually trying to do.

If `category` is a variable, then you don't have to use `"$category"` in `contains()`, you can simply use `category` unless you're evaluating some expression.

But if this is not your use-case and you just want to get rid of the error; simply add an escape character before the $ symbol:

```
assert slurped.pCategories.contains("\$category")
```

If you could elaborate on your use-case, maybe we can help.